# Scale up the dimensions of the internal image in the sprite and display 3rd image from the sprite

Tags: html, sprite, css-sprites

I am preparing my sprite by reducing the dimensions of the image. Successfully I prepare the sprite and load complete sprite on the web page using flex property.
Problem 1:
But when I want to scale up the dimension of second image from 100x100 px to 300 x 300px and want to display in the div just 2nd image then I am unable to resize the dimensions whole sprite disappear.

Problem2:
When I change the position of the sprite then it will cut the sprite images.
Here is a code to load the whole sprite.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>About Us Sprite</title>

<style>
    body {
      background-color: grey;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100%;
      width:100%; /* Ensure the body takes up the full viewport height */
     
      margin: 10 0 10 0px; /* Remove default margin for body */
    }

    /* Set the dimensions for the container and adjust the background-position */
    
    
     .group4 {
      background-image: url('Group 4.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      /*  */
        width:506px;
        height:413px;
      background-position: 0 0;
    }
    
    .about{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-position: 300 300;
    
    }
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- About Us Section -->
 
    <div class="group4"></div>
    <!--Display 3rd image from 1st row-->
    <div class="about"></div>
   
  
</body>
</html>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>`
```

Please modify my for about div, I want to display 3rd image from 1st row changing its dimension from 100x100 to 300x300px. How can I calculate the background-image position for the 3rd image and display it scaling up its dimensions.

[Sprite Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sW2w.png)